# Converting Entity Key to urlsafe string

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

this question is related to the new Cloud Firestore in 'Datastore Mode'.

In the old ndb datastore, it is easy to convert an Entity key into an url_safe string:

`entity.key.urlsafe()`

But this does not work with the new 'Database Mode'.

How can I convert an entity key to be a urlsafe string?

Answer (score 1):

The [(from|to)_legacy_urlsafe()](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/keys.html) methods can be used:

**From entity key to urlsafe string:**

```
my_entity_key = Key('SomeKind', 'id_123')
urlsafe_string = my_entity_key.to_legacy_urlsafe()
```

**From urlsafe string to entity key:**

```
from google.cloud import datastore

entity_key = datastore.Key.from_legacy_urlsafe(urlsafe_string)
```